# Why can't many to many relationships be shown in the data dictionary?

Tags: database-design

I have read and seen that many-to-many relationships in an ER diagram can be shown by adding another table which includes the primary key of both tables as reference keys.  Here `payment_party_id` is the primary key of the `payment_party` table and `receipt_party_id` is the primary key of the `receipt_party` table. What is the logical reason behind that:

```
  field                  key
  ---------------------  -----------------------       
  payment_party_id       reference key
  receipt_party_id       reference key
```

Can anyone explain why this additional table is added only with reference keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many-to-many relationships can be shown directly on ***logical* entity-relationship drawings**.  Some modelling tools don't depict logical ERDs.  They only depict ***physical* ERDs**.  In a physical ERD a many-to-many relationship is implemented using an **intersection table**.

Any intersection table requires a foreign key (OP: "reference key") to each table that is part of the relationship.  If the intersection table implements a simple many-to-many relationship, then the combination of the two foreign keys also form the **compound primary key** of the intersection table.

In other words, the example from the question would in fact look like this:

```
field                  key
---------------------  -------------------------------------
payment_party_id       primary key, foreign (reference) key
receipt_party_id       primary key, foreign (reference) key
```